# Разблокировка display: block

Tags: javascript

всем привет

Необходимо при выборе `connectid value=7` и `presentId value=1` разблокировать появляющее окно `inbound_from (style="display: block;")`
и чтобы в этом окне выбирались только `value=1, value=6, value=8`

Немного начал...

```
$('#inbound_from').change(function() {
    if($('#connectid').val() != 7 && ($('#presentId').val() != 1))
    $('#inbound_from').val("");
    $('#inbound_from').attr("display",block);
});
```

Comment: `attr` - предназначен на установку аттрибутов, а не стилей. За стили отвечает функция `css`.

Comment: Да это я понял, но все равно не разблокируется

Comment: Вам не кажется странным, что вы пытаетесь сделать событие на форму, которая скрыта? Интересно, как вы делаете изменение формы? И вообще это не нормально применять на форму событие `change`, на сколько помню это на `input`.

Comment: Поправьте меня пожалуйста как правильно разблокировать,

Comment: $('#inbound_from').input(function() {
    if($('#connectid').val() != 7 && ($('#presentId').val() != 1))
    $('#inbound_from').val("");
    $('#inbound_from').css("display",none);
});

Comment: @And событие change - всплывающее. Его можно вешать хоть на форму, хоть на body, хоть на document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Открывает все
$("#inbound_from").append() ("<option value=""></option>") &&
//или
$("#inbound_from").append("<option value="2">Hello</option>")
```

Comment: И можно еще так  $('#inbound_from').attr("disabled",false);

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
$('#inbound_from').show();
```

Comment: так даже не реагирует